# Does Parallels support 3.18.0-kali3-amd64?

Tags: kernel, kali-linux, parallels

I'm not able to find information on which kernels Parallels supports. I'm trying to figure out if Parallels 10.1 supports this kernel since Parallels Tools will not install no matter what I try.

Here's the /var/log/parallels-tools-install.log:

```
2015-07-14T22:37:24-0400:

Parallels Tools 10.0.1-27695 Installer started.
2015-07-14T22:37:24-0400: Failed to setup console printk level.
2015-07-14T22:37:34-0400: execCmd: ./installer/pm.sh check_guest_tools 2>&1 [1]
2015-07-14T22:37:56-0400: Hit http://http.kali.org kali Release.gpg
Hit http://security.kali.org kali/updates Release.gpg
Hit http://http.kali.org kali Release
Hit http://security.kali.org kali/updates Release
Hit http://http.kali.org kali/main Sources
Hit http://http.kali.org kali/non-free Sources
Hit http://security.kali.org kali/updates/main Sources
Hit http://http.kali.org kali/contrib Sources
Hit http://security.kali.org kali/updates/contrib Sources
Hit http://http.kali.org kali/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.kali.org kali/updates/non-free Sources
Hit http://http.kali.org kali/non-free amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.kali.org kali/updates/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://http.kali.org kali/contrib amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.kali.org kali/updates/contrib amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.kali.org kali/updates/non-free amd64 Packages
Ign http://http.kali.org kali/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign http://http.kali.org kali/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://http.kali.org kali/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://http.kali.org kali/main Translation-en
Ign http://http.kali.org kali/non-free Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.kali.org kali/updates/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign http://http.kali.org kali/non-free Translation-en
Ign http://security.kali.org kali/updates/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://security.kali.org kali/updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.kali.org kali/updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://security.kali.org kali/updates/non-free Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.kali.org kali/updates/non-free Translation-en
Reading package lists...
Return code from apt-get update is 0
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
linux-headers-3.18.0-kali3-common linux-kbuild-3.18
linux-headers-3.18.0-kali3-amd64
Authentication warning overridden.
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-3.18.0-kali3-common.
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 323173 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking linux-headers-3.18.0-kali3-common (from .../linux-headers-3.18.0-kali3-common_3.18.6-1~kali2_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-kbuild-3.18.
Unpacking linux-kbuild-3.18 (from .../linux-kbuild-3.18_3.18.3-0kali1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-3.18.0-kali3-amd64.
Unpacking linux-headers-3.18.0-kali3-amd64 (from .../linux-headers-3.18.0-kali3-amd64_3.18.6-1~kali2_amd64.deb) ...
Setting up linux-headers-3.18.0-kali3-common (3.18.6-1~kali2) ...
Setting up linux-kbuild-3.18 (3.18.3-0kali1) ...
Setting up linux-headers-3.18.0-kali3-amd64 (3.18.6-1~kali2) ...
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
dkms linux-headers-amd64
Authentication warning overridden.
Selecting previously unselected package dkms.
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 334151 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking dkms (from .../dkms_2.2.0.3-1.2_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-amd64.
Unpacking linux-headers-amd64 (from .../linux-headers-amd64_3.18+63+kali2015-07-14T22:38:23-0400: 2.1_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up dkms (2.2.0.3-1.2) ...
Setting up linux-headers-amd64 (3.18+63+kali2.1) ...
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
libcupscgi1 libcupsmime1 libcupsppdc1 libslp1 cups-ppdc libcupsfilters1
cups-filters cups foomatic-filters foomatic-db-engine libart-2.0-2
libcupsdriver1 libescpr1 libgutenprint2 foomatic-db-compressed-ppds
ghostscript-cups libhpmud0 libsane-hpaio hplip-data printer-driver-hpcups
python-reportlab hplip printer-driver-all printer-driver-c2050
printer-driver-c2esp printer-driver-cjet printer-driver-escpr
printer-driver-foo2zjs printer-driver-gutenprint printer-driver-hpijs
printer-driver-m2300w printer-driver-min12xxw printer-driver-pnm2ppa
printer-driver-postscript-hp printer-driver-ptouch printer-driver-pxljr
printer-driver-sag-gdi printer-driver-splix python-renderpm
python-reportlab-accel hpijs mscompress
Extracting templates from packages: 71%
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
Authentication warning overridden.
Selecting previously unselected package libcupscgi1:amd64.
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 334201 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libcupscgi1:amd64 (from .../libcupscgi1_1.5.3-5+deb7u6_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcupsmime1:amd64.
Unpacking libcupsmime1:amd64 (from .../libcupsmime1_1.5.3-5+deb7u6_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcupsppdc1:amd64.
Unpacking libcupsppdc1:amd64 (from .../libcupsppdc1_1.5.3-5+deb7u6_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libslp1.
Unpacking libslp1 (from .../libslp1_1.2.1-9_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package cups-ppdc.
Unpacking cups-ppdc (from .../cups-ppdc_1.5.3-5+deb7u6_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcupsfilters1:amd64.
Unpacking libcupsfilters1:amd64 (from .../libcupsfilters1_1.0.18-2.1+deb7u2_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package cups-filters.
Unpacking cups-filters (from .../cups-filters_1.0.18-2.1+deb7u2_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package cups.
Unpacking cups (from .../cups_1.5.3-5+deb7u6_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package foomatic-filters.
Unpacking foomatic-filters (from .../foomatic-filters_4.0.17-1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package foomatic-db-engine.
Unpacking foomatic-db-engine (from .../foomatic-db-engine_4.0.8-3_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libart-2.0-2:amd64.
Unpacking libart-2.0-2:amd64 (from .../libart-2.0-2_2.3.21-2_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcupsdriver1:amd64.
Unpacking libcupsdriver1:amd64 (from .../libcupsdriver1_1.5.3-5+deb7u6_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libescpr1:amd64.
Unpacking libescpr1:amd64 (from .../libescpr1_1.1.1-2_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgutenprint2.
Unpacking libgutenprint2 (from .../libgutenprint2_5.2.9-1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package foomatic-db-compressed-ppds.
Unpacking foomatic-db-compressed-ppds (from .../foomatic-db-compressed-ppds_20120523-1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package ghostscript-cups.
Unpacking ghostscript-cups (from .../ghostscript-cups_9.05~dfsg-6.3+deb7u1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libhpmud0.
Unpacking libhpmud0 (from .../libhpmud0_3.12.6-3.1+deb7u1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libsane-hpaio.
Unpacking libsane-hpaio (from .../libsan2015-07-14T22:38:27-0400: e-hpaio_3.12.6-3.1+deb7u1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package hplip-data.
Unpacking hplip-data (from .../hplip-data_3.12.6-3.1+deb7u1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package printer-driver-hpcups.
Unpacking printer-driver-hpcups (from .../printer-driver-hpcups_3.12.6-3.1+deb7u1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-reportlab.
Unpacking python-reportlab (from .../python-reportlab_2.5-1.1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package hplip.
Unpacking hplip (from .../hplip_3.12.6-3.1+deb7u1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package printer-driver-all.
Unpacking printer-driver-all (from .../printer-driver-all_0.20120416_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package printer-driver-c2050.
Unpacking printer-driver-c2050 (from .../printer-driver-c2050_0.3b-4_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package printer-driver-c2esp.
Unpacking printer-driver-c2esp (from .../printer-driver-c2esp_24-2_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package printer-driver-cjet.
Unpacking printer-driver-cjet (from .../printer-driver-cjet_0.8.9-3_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package printer-driver-escpr.
Unpacking printer-driver-escpr (from .../printer-driver-escpr_1.1.1-2_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package printer-driver-foo2zjs.
Unpacking printer-driver-foo2zjs (from .../printer-driver-foo2zjs_20120510dfsg0-1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package printer-driver-gutenprint.
Unpacking printer-driver-gutenprint (from .../printer-driver-gutenprint_5.2.9-1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package printer-driver-hpijs.
Unpacking printer-driver-hpijs (from .../printer-driver-hpijs_3.12.6-3.1+deb7u1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package printer-driver-m2300w.
Unpacking printer-driver-m2300w (from .../printer-driver-m2300w_0.51-7_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package printer-driver-min12xxw.
Unpacking printer-driver-min12xxw (from .../printer-driver-min12xxw_0.0.9-6_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package printer-driver-pnm2ppa.
Unpacking printer-driver-pnm2ppa (from .../printer-driver-pnm2ppa_1.13-4_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package printer-driver-postscript-hp.
Unpacking printer-driver-postscript-hp (from .../printer-driver-postscript-hp_3.12.6-3.1+deb7u1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package printer-driver-ptouch.
Unpacking printer-driver-ptouch (from .../printer-driver-ptouch_1.3-4_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package printer-driver-pxljr.
Unpacking printer-driver-pxljr (from .../printer-driver-pxljr_1.3+repack0-2_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package printer-driver-sag-gdi.
Unpacking printer-driver-sag-gdi (from .../printer-driver-sag-gdi_0.1-3_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package printer-driver-splix.
Unpacking printer-driver-splix (from .../printer-driver-splix_2.0.0+svn306-2_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-renderpm.
Unpacking python-renderpm (from .../python-renderpm_2.5-1.1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-reportlab-accel.
Unpacking python-reportlab-accel (from .../python-reportlab-accel_2.5-1.1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package hpijs.
Unpacking hpijs (from .../hpijs_3.12.6-3.1+deb7u1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mscompress.
Unpacking mscompress (from .../mscompress_0.3-4_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Setting up libcupscgi1:amd64 (1.5.3-5+deb7u6) ...
Setting up libcupsmime1:amd64 (1.5.3-5+deb7u6) ...
Setting up libcupsppdc1:amd64 (1.5.3-5+deb7u6) ...
Setting up libslp1 (1.2.1-9) ...
Setting up cups-ppdc (1.5.3-5+deb7u6) ...
Setting up libcupsfilters1:amd64 (1.0.18-2.1+deb7u2) ...
Setting up cups-filters (1.0.18-2.1+deb7u2) ...
Setting up cups (1.5.3-5+deb7u6) ...
update-rc.d: As per Kali policy, cups init script is left disabled.
insserv: war2015-07-14T22:38:39-0400: ning: current start runlevel(s) (empty) of script `cups' overrides LSB defaults (2 3 4 5).
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (1 2 3 4 5) of script `cups' overrides LSB defaults (1).
Setting up foomatic-filters (4.0.17-1) ...

Creating config file /etc/foomatic/filter.conf with new version
Setting up foomatic-db-engine (4.0.8-3) ...
Setting up libart-2.0-2:amd64 (2.3.21-2) ...
Setting up libcupsdriver1:amd64 (1.5.3-5+deb7u6) ...
Setting up libescpr1:amd64 (1.1.1-2) ...
Setting up libgutenprint2 (5.2.9-1) ...
Setting up foomatic-db-compressed-ppds (20120523-1) ...
Setting up ghostscript-cups (9.05~dfsg-6.3+deb7u1) ...
Setting up libhpmud0 (3.12.6-3.1+deb7u1) ...
Setting up libsane-hpaio (3.12.6-3.1+deb7u1) ...
Setting up hplip-data (3.12.6-3.1+deb7u1) ...
Setting up printer-driver-hpcups (3.12.6-3.1+deb7u1) ...
Setting up python-reportlab (2.5-1.1) ...
Setting up hplip (3.12.6-3.1+deb7u1) ...
Creating/updating hplip user account...
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
Setting up printer-driver-all (0.20120416) ...
Setting up printer-driver-c2050 (0.3b-4) ...
Setting up printer-driver-c2esp (24-2) ...
Setting up printer-driver-cjet (0.8.9-3) ...
Setting up printer-driver-escpr (1.1.1-2) ...
Setting up printer-driver-foo2zjs (20120510dfsg0-1) ...
Setting up printer-driver-gutenprint (5.2.9-1) ...
No Gutenprint PPD files to update.
[....] Reloading Common Unix Printing System: cupsd[?25l7[1G[[31mFAIL[39;49m8[?12l[?25h [31mfailed![39;49m
Setting up printer-driver-hpijs (3.12.6-3.1+deb7u1) ...
Setting up printer-driver-m2300w (0.51-7) ...
Setting up printer-driver-min12xxw (0.0.9-6) ...
Setting up printer-driver-pnm2ppa (1.13-4) ...
Setting up printer-driver-postscript-hp (3.12.6-3.1+deb7u1) ...
Setting up printer-driver-ptouch (1.3-4) ...
Setting up printer-driver-pxljr (1.3+repack0-2) ...
Setting up printer-driver-sag-gdi (0.1-3) ...
Setting up printer-driver-splix (2.0.0+svn306-2) ...
Setting up python-renderpm (2.5-1.1) ...
Setting up python-reportlab-accel (2.5-1.1) ...
Setting up hpijs (3.12.6-3.1+deb7u1) ...
Setting up mscompress (0.3-4) ...
2015-07-14T22:38:40-0400: execCmd: ./installer/pm.sh download_guest_tools 2>&1 [0]
Started installation of Parallels Guest Tools version '10.0.1.27695'

Tue Jul 14 22:38:40 EDT 2015
Start installation or upgrade of Guest Tools
new version of parallels tools
Installed Guest Tools were not found
Perform installation into the /usr/lib/parallels-tools directory
cat: /usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/../version: No such file or directory
Start installation of prl_eth kernel module
make: Entering directory `/usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods'
cd prl_eth/pvmnet && make
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_eth/pvmnet'
make -C /lib/modules/3.18.0-kali3-amd64/build M=/usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_eth/pvmnet
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.18.0-kali3-amd64'
LD /usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_eth/pvmnet/built-in.o
CC [M] /usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_eth/pvmnet/pvmnet.o
/usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_eth/pvmnet/pvmnet.c: In function ‘pvmnet_pci_init’:
/usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_eth/pvmnet/pvmnet.c:101:19: error: macro "alloc_netdev" requires 4 arguments, but only 3 given
/usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_eth/pvmnet/pvmnet.c:100:8: error: ‘alloc_netdev’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_eth/pvmnet/pvmnet.c:100:8: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_eth/pvmnet/pvmnet.c: In function ‘pvmnet_setup’:
/usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_eth/pvmnet/pvmnet.c:420:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘SET_ETHTOOL_OPS’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
/usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_eth/pvmnet/pvmnet.c:420:24: error: ‘pvmnet_ethtool_ops’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_eth/pvmnet/pvmnet.c: At top level:
/usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_eth/pvmnet/pvmnet.c:404:13: warning: ‘pvmnet_setup’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[5]: *** [/usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_eth/pvmnet/pvmnet.o] Error 1
make[4]: *** [_module_/usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_eth/pvmnet] Error 2
make[3]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.18.0-kali3-amd64'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_eth/pvmnet'
make: *** [installme] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods'
Error: could not build kernel modules
Error: failed to install kernel modules
2015-07-14T22:38:40-0400: execCmd: ./install --install [143]
2015-07-14T22:38:40-0400: Error: An error occurred when installing Parallels Tools. Please go to /var/log/parallels-tools-install.log for more information.
2015-07-14T22:38:48-0400: Exiting with code 1
```

I updated sources, did apt-get update, upgrade and dist-upgrade. I also made sure to run the tools installer as: `chmod -R 777 . && ./install`.

Comment: What error messages did you get?

Comment: Did you consider installing Linux on separate partitions and booting that... ?

Comment: I'd really rather not install on separate partition, I have a bootable USB, but the VM would be much more convenient if I could get it working. The error I get is, "Some components needed for Parallels Tools installation are missing in your system. Do you want to download these components automatically?" And then, "An error occurred while installing Parallels Tools. Please go to /var/log/parallels-tools-install.log for more information."

Answer (score 1):

[GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) is very probably an ordinary application built on standard Linux [syscalls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call). So the particular version of the kernel does not matter much. It should run with an old kernel (e.g. a 3.1) or with a new one (e.g. a 4.1)

[Parallels desktop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallels_Desktop_for_Mac) is a virtualization package for MacOSX. Since it is using [hypervisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor) technology (hence emulating some PC *hardware*) it should be able to run any kind of OS, including most Linux kernels (and other OSes like GNU/Hurd).

You may download GNU parallel source code and compile it (if you still have issues, give the exact commands you did and the error messages you've got).

See also [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216052/kali-1-3-installing-parallel-tools) related question.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't referring to the command-line utility, but Parallels Desktop 10 for Mac where I'm running Kali as a VM.

Comment: I've read that Parallels 9 Tools didn't support some kernels so I was wondering if there was any way to check which ones version 10 supports.